# how to view the site after deploying it

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment

This might be a really stupid question and make you guys laugh. I've deployed my whole website using the copy website tool to my FTP server, but then how do I go and visit the site that I just deployed?

The domain name is: H204716.dreamsparkhosting.com however when I navigate there through my browser it says

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the file name of your default page?  Its possible that if it's odd enough (ie, not home.html or default.aspx or index.html etc.) that the site doesn't know what page to load.

Have you tried
http://H204716.dreamsparkhosting.com/myDefaultPageName.html?

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to log into your DreamHost account and explicitly set the default page for your website.  That way your users can just type in http://yourdomain.com/ as opposed to ...yourdomain.com/i-know-the-defaultpagename.aspx